# Beautiful soup check for tag in tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, scraper

I'm using Beautiful Soup 4 to scrape a page. There's a block of text I don't want:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: center"><b>
                            <span lang="EN-US" style="font-family: Arial; color: blue">
                            <font size="4">1 </font></span>
                            <span lang="AR-SA" dir="RTL" style="font-family: Arial; color: blue">
                            <font size="4">&#1600;</font></span><span lang="EN-US" style="font-family: Arial; color: blue"><font size="4"> 
                            с&#1199;р&#1241; фати&#1211;&#1241;</font></span></b></p>
```

The thing that makes it unique is that it has a  tag. I already used findall() to get all the

tags. So now I have a for loop like:

```
for el in doc.findall('p'):
    if el.hasChildTag('b'):
        break;
```

Unfortunately bs4 has no "hasChildTag" function

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to use css selectors also.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

```
soup.select("p b")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for elem in soup.findAll('p'):
    if elem.findChildren('b'):
        continue #skip the elem with "b", and continue with the loop
    #do stuff with the elem
```